# detect moves on mobile phones to call javascript functions

Tags: javascript, mobile, cross-browser, detection

I have a website that I would like to be able to also play in mobiles.

In the interface I mostly use javascript. How can I detect the moves of the user's fingers on the screen , so I can call the right javascript functions?

For example , in my photogallery I have
`<input type="button" onClick="imagenext();"/>` to call the `imagenext`, so the gallery renders the next image.

In case of mobile phones, how can I do something like
`onFingerMoved="imagenext();"`

Or even better, how can I add the move events to my already existing code? Like
`onClick or onMove= function();`

And of course I am looking for cross-mobile browser solutions

Forgive my childish examples, I am a begginer

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery Mobile to accomplish this. Here's their [api documentation](http://api.jquerymobile.com/swipe/#global-nav) for the swipe event. You can implement what you are trying to do as follows:

```
$( "body" ).on( "swipe", function() {
    imageNext();
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have ontouchstart, ontouchend, ontouchmove and can put that on anything you like.

```
var _touches = {
    'touchstart'    : {'x' : -1, 'y' : -1}
  , 'touchmove'     : {'x' : -1, 'y' : -1} 
  , 'touchend'      : false
  , 'direction'     : 'undetermined'
};

function touchHandler (event) {
  var touch
    , xSwipe
    , ySwipe;

  if (typeof event !== 'undefined'){    
    // for vanilla javascript use event.touches
    if (typeof event.originalEvent.touches !== 'undefined') {
        touch = event.originalEvent.touches[0];

        switch (event.originalEvent.type) {
            case 'touchstart':
            case 'mousedown':
                _touches[event.originalEvent.type].x = touch.pageX;
                _touches[event.originalEvent.type].y = touch.pageY;
                break;
            case 'touchmove':
            case 'mousemove':
                _touches[event.originalEvent.type].x = touch.pageX;
                _touches[event.originalEvent.type].y = touch.pageY;
                break;
            case 'touchend':
            case 'mouseup':
                    _touches[event.originalEvent.type] = true;
                        if (_touches.touchstart.x > -1 && _touches.touchmove.x > -1) {
                        xSwipe = Math.abs(_touches.touchstart.x - _touches.touchmove.x);
                        ySwipe = Math.abs(_touches.touchstart.y - _touches.touchmove.y);
                        }
                        if (xSwipe > ySwipe && xSwipe > (getViewport().width * .33)) {
                            _touches.direction = _touches.touchstart.x < _touches.touchmove.x ? 'left' : 'right';

                            if (_touches.direction === 'left') {
                                // do something
                            } else if (_touches.direction === 'right') {
                                // do something
                            }
                        }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

$element.on('touchstart touchmove touchend', function (e) {
    touchHandler(e);
});
```